# MongoDB find between the dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nodes

I've got the next data in the MongoDB:

```
{
...
 name: Alex,
 createdAt: {"$date":"2021-03-09T20:01:57.488Z"},
...
}
```

And I try to implement the range date query like this:

```
        MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }

          const dbo = db.db('dbname');

          dbo.collection('users').find({ 
              createdAt: {
                  $gte: new Date(dateFrom).toISOString(),
                  $lt: new Date(dateTo).toISOString()
                }
            }).toArray( 
            (err, res) => {
              if (err) { return reject(err); }

              db.close();
              return resolve(res);
          });
        });
```

And always have zero-result without errors..

How coud I do the right query?

Comment: Check Schema, what is the type of your createdAt field?

Comment: Also check `dateFrom`, `dateTo` to ensure they are indeed valid dates, and that they convert correctly, taking into account localizations.

Comment: The dates in the database are ISODate() datatypes, but your code is trying to find the dates as a String datatype.  Will never find them since the string datatype and the ISODate datatype are different.  Try removing the .toISOString() in your query to allow the query to use date datatypes against the data instead of strings.